# no se despliegan datos con extJS y C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, extjs

Tengo un problema con extJS y c# no me muestra ningun dato solo un encabezado, solo quiero mostrar los registros de mi tabla sql, pero no he podido, mi backend funciona bien y si devuelve los registros de mi BD, el problema esta es que no se estan bindeando, por lo que creo que esta mal mi archivo JS y no encuentro el error para que se muestren los registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

app.js

```js
       Ext.require([
            'Ext.grid.*',
            'Ext.data.*',
            'Ext.panel.*',
            'Ext.util.*'
        ]);


        Ext.application({
            name: 'Fiddle',

            launch: function () {
                var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                    // Load data at once
                    autoLoad: true,
                    // Override default http proxy settings
                    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                        pageParam: false, //to remove param "page"
                        startParam: false, //to remove param "start"
                        limitParam: false, //to remove param "limit"
                        noCache: false, //to remove param "_dc"
                        // Call web service method using GET syntax
                        url: 'GetCustomers',
                        // Ask for Json response
                        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
                    }),
                    // Root variable
                    root: 'data',
                    // Record identifier
                    id: 'EmpleadoId',
                    //reader:Jreader,
                    // Fields declaration
                    fields: ['EmpleadoId', 'NombreEmpleado', 'DirectorId'],
                });


                var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    // Set store
                    store: myStore,
                    // Columns definition
                    columns: [
                        { dataIndex: 'EmpleadoId', header: 'Empleado Id' },
                        { dataIndex: 'NombreEmpleado', header: 'Nombre Empleado' },
                        { dataIndex: 'DirectorId', header: 'Director Id' }
                    ],
                    // Render grid to dom element with id set to panel
                    renderTo: 'whitespace',
                    width: 422,
                    height: 300
                });

            }
        });
```

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/charts-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="whitespace"></div>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult GetCustomers()
{
    List<Empleados> lstPersona = new List<Empleados>();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=PC;Database=TestPersona;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpleadoId,NombreEmpleado,DirectorId FROM Empleados", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Empleados emp = new Empleados();
        emp.EmpleadoId = Convert.ToInt16(dr["EmpleadoId"]);
        emp.NombreEmpleado = dr["NombreEmpleado"].ToString();
        emp.DirectorId = Convert.ToInt16(dr["DirectorId"]);


        lstPersona.Add(emp);
    }

    con.Close();
    JsonResult res = Json(new { data = lstPersona }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de ExtJs estás usando?

Comment: @Phi es la version 6.2.0.981